# Where to put functions I just need for testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a couple Java classes which have blackbox test cases that just exercise the public API of the class. To write some whitebox test cases I needed to write some getters that are not part of the public API, but need to be visible to the test class.

How can I handle these functions?

Comment: Do you have any code examples? Sometimes you don't actually need getters, a clever use of mocks gets the same effect but more elegantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make getters package default and place your test class in the same package.

Comment: OP: This is the most common solution in the Java world.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Currently, I have my test cases in a separate test.module package tree.

Comment: Tests may sit in different location, obviously, so they are not included in production code. But package should be the same.

Comment: I always thought that the directory structure has to match the packages. When I create the list of classes that go into production, I can just use `sed` to remove the `*Test.class` from my production code though.

Comment: It must match package structure from classpath level. You can have to directories `src` and `test` and have the same correct package structure under them. Compile them to `classes` and `test-classes` and include both in classpath for testing. That's how it is typically done.

Answer (score 0):

The "package default" answer is a reasonable approach, but I question adding anything to main source for the sole purpose of testing. I also question the need for what you call "whitebox" testing of a class. If other objects always interact with objects of your class through its public API, why would you test anything besides that? My recommendation would be that you abandon this approach and stick to testing only your public API.

Answer (score 0):

I often break out and expose the "code only" parts as `public static` methods, so the code can be unit tested. It works for me.